# Function to detect peaks within an array of float values in Arduino? When graphed, displays an ECG reading?

Tags: arrays, arduino

I currently have this array of 2560 values that when graphed, forms an ECG. I've plotted this in MATLAB with the following figure resulting (axis is [0,2560] for x and [-1, 2] for y. Sampling frequency is 256 Hz, so I've graphed 10 seconds here. This was generated from ECGSYN off Physionet, a single lead ECG waveform plotter.

Matlab Output of ECG data:

[image]

I exported this as a csv and defined these values this as a float array with 2560 elements in Arduino. Based on the image, we can see about 10 peaks present, and I've been trying to calculate the number of QRS complex peaks in this function in Arduino (with the ultimate goal of finding beats per minute).

Have not been having much luck, as the recorded number of peaks is about 300+ (and should be 10). I've added the relevant portions of my code to this post below with a screenshot from the serial monitor. I've honed down my issue to the for loop somewhere inside, but have not been able to accurately determine peak numbers. My goal was to find maximums where the next value in the array is smaller than the current, and the previous value in the array is also smaller than the current. There is also the condition that the values that count as peaks must be above a threshold of .8 (to make sure a QRS complex is counted and not a T or P wave of the ECG).

Please let me know if I can provide additional information here. Apologies for any unclarity, as this is my first post, and my coding syntax isn't the most accurate (relatively new to Arduino). Thanks for your help.

Serial Monitor Output of BPM and peak number:

[image]

These are the initialized variables, array (left all the 2560 elements out), and the function for BPM.

```
const int arraySize = 2560;
int total = 0;
const float Sixty_BPM [arraySize] PROGMEM = {
// All my array elements
};

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int get_bpm()
{
  int Num_peaks = 0;
  float threshold_min = 1.0 ;
  float delaycalc = .1;
  for (int x = 1 ; x < arraySize-1; x++) {        
    if ((Sixty_BPM[x] - Sixty_BPM[x-1] > delaycalc )  &&  (Sixty_BPM[x+1] - Sixty_BPM[x] < 0) && (Sixty_BPM[x] > threshold_min)){ 
       Num_peaks++;
    }
  }
    Serial.print("NUMBER OF PEAKS IS");
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(Num_peaks);
    Serial.print("\n");
    float peakspersec = (float) Num_peaks / (((float) arraySize / 256));
    float bpm = peakspersec * 60;
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("BPM is ");
    Serial.print(bpm);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("\n");
    return bpm;
}
```

Update:

Graphed the peaks in MATLAB as per Ax the B's recommendation. This definitely showed me the formula isn't calculating anywhere close to what I intend it to work as. Here's an output of the peaks plotted against the ECG (no pattern to peaks it looks like).

Index locations of peaks overlayed on ECG:

[image]

I tried out a smoothing average filter in MATLAB and did not see a large difference. The data itself is incredibly clean (basically no noise).

Any other thoughts about how to edit this peak detection formula? Thanks for help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the for loop with

```
Serial.print("peaks = [");
for (int x = 1 ; x < arraySize-1; x++) {        
  if ((Sixty_BPM[x-1] < threshold_min) && (Sixty_BPM[x] >= threshold_min)) { 
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(x);
    Num_peaks++;
  }
}
Serial.println("]");
```

to just count how many times the values went above threshold. If its not working then you can copy-paste the peaks array from serial console into matlab and plot it over your plot to see where they were detected. If there are clustered multiple false peaks around the threshold line you may want to do some filtering/averaging first.

Comment: Strange, the false peaks are at locations there the value is clearly under threshold, maybe try printing the value if Sixty_BPM[x] to see whats going on. Also, the condition may also be simplified to

    if ((Sixty_BPM[x] > Sixty_BPM[x-1])  &&  (Sixty_BPM[x] > Sixty_BPM[x+1]) && (Sixty_BPM[x] > threshold_min)) 

I am not sure what the delaycalc is supposed to do there, but it certainly can produce false negatives.